# Full Calendar resourceTimeGrid layout question

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am implementing Fullcalendar using the following code (WIP)
This puts the events inside the calendar the correct way. But by Default the calender uses the starting time to position the event blocks inside the calendar.
I would like the implement my events like a Trello board, so basically they all start on top in the same row. I've added a picture for clearing up the idea.

[image]

```
    let calendar = new Calendar(calendarElement, {
      schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
      locale: nlLocale,
      timeZone: "UTC",
      allDaySlot: false,
      plugins: [ 
        resourceTimeGridPlugin,
      ],
      initialView: 'resourceTimeGridDay',
      resources: `${window.location.href}/getRoomsJSON`,
      eventDisplay: 'block',
      events: [
        { id: '1', resourceId: '2', start: '2020-12-21T02:00:00', title: 'event 1' },
        { id: '2', resourceId: '2', start: '2020-12-21T05:00:00', title: 'event 2' },
        { id: '3', resourceId: '3', start: '2020-12-21T03:00:00', title: 'event 4' },
        { id: '4', resourceId: '4', start: '2020-12-21T00:30:00', title: 'event 5' }
      ],
      contentHeight: 'auto',
      eventTimeFormat: { // like '14:30:00'
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        meridiem: false
      }
    });
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/resource-daygrid-view is what you need I think

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did the trick!

Comment: No problem. If you have a solution, write it in the Answers block below, don't write "updates" to your question. This is a question-and-answer site. The answer is not part of the question, they are separate :-). See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Ah I did not noticed that section. I changed to an answer now, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use `resource-daygrid` instead of `resource-timegrid` This gave me a layout very simular to the image above. Next I applied normal styling and voilà we have a identical calendar.